# IllegalStateException: Can't overwrite cause in Guava map.put

Tags: java, jboss, guava

I create a map using

```
new MapMaker().softValues().maximumSize(cacheSize).makeMap();
```

This seemed to work fine, however, I sometimes get the following exception after accessing right after deploying on the server and putting new elements into the map:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't overwrite cause
  at java.lang.Throwable.initCause(Throwable.java:320)
  at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.findClass(RepositoryClassLoader.java:624)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
  at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClassImpl(RepositoryClassLoader.java:474)
  at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClass(RepositoryClassLoader.java:415)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
  at com.google.common.collect.CustomConcurrentHashMap$2.iterator(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:828)
  at java.util.AbstractCollection.remove(AbstractCollection.java:241)
  at com.google.common.collect.CustomConcurrentHashMap$Segment.removeFromChain(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2599)
  at com.google.common.collect.CustomConcurrentHashMap$Segment.processPendingCleanup(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2772)
  at com.google.common.collect.CustomConcurrentHashMap$Segment.runLockedCleanup(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2860)
  at com.google.common.collect.CustomConcurrentHashMap$Segment.preWriteCleanup(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2806)
  at com.google.common.collect.CustomConcurrentHashMap$Segment.put(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2374)
  at com.google.common.collect.CustomConcurrentHashMap.put(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:3346)
  at my.app.cache.CacheImplGoogleGuava.put(CacheImplGoogleGuava.java:36)
...
```

What could be the reason?

--- Updated:

JBoss version is 5.

Setting a breakpoint in Throwable.initCause revealed `ClassNotFoundException` with message:
`Invalid use of destroyed classloader for com.google.common.collect.Iterators, UCL destroyed at:`
and with Stacktrace

```
ClassNotFoundException(Throwable).initCause(Throwable):320
UnifiedClassLoader3(RepositoryClassLoader).findClass(String):628
...
UnifiedClassLoader3(ClassLoader).loadClass(String):248
CustomConcurrentHashMap$2.iterator():828
CustomConcurrentHashMap$2(AbstractCollection<E>).remove(Object):241
CustomConcurrentHashMap$Segment.enqueueCleanup(...):2738
CustomConcurrentHashMap$Segment.unsetValue(...):2662
CustomConcurrentHashMap<K, V>.reclaimValue(...)
CustomConcurrentHashMap$SoftValueReference<K, V>.finalizeReferent():1637
...
Method.invoke:574
Finalizer.claenUp:154
Finalizer.run:127
```

From the stacktrace, it seems as if an object in the map was finalized where in `finalizeReferent` the class `com.google.common.collect.Iterators` cannot be loaded.

Comment: This seems more like a JBoss problem than a Guava problem.  You're just happening to hit it as a result of Guava code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem seems to be unrelated to `MapMaker` or Guava in general.

You only see an exception that happens while handling another exception (unfortunately).

`Throwable.initCause()` throws an exception when it's called while there was already a cause specified for the current `Throwable` (either via the method or the constructor`.

The `RepositoryClassLoader.findClass()` method seems to be handling some exception that it expects not to have a cause, but in fact it already has a cause set, which triggers this exception.

Unfortunately the exception you see here hides the actual exception (which would probably be much more important for solving the problem).

Try to put a breakpoit at `Throwable.initCause()` at line 320 or at `RepositoryClassLoader.findClass()` (at line 624) and reproduce the problem to (hopefully) see the "real" exception in the local variables view of your IDE.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the fact that the original exception is "hidden" comes from a possible JBoss bug 552 that was not completely resolved. My original ClassNotFoundException exception (see updated question) however, seems to have a cause that lies somewhere in Guava, no?

Comment: @stacktracer: it's possible that this is caused by something in Guava, but I've never seen that error message and it seems to be JBoss-specific.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a known JBoss bug that might have already been resolved in new versions of the platform.  Here is at least one similar bug:

[JBREM-552: cannot init cause of ClassCastException](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBREM-552)

You might try upgrading your version of JBoss (though this particular bug implies the fix was in 2006) or filing another bug if your version is up to date.  It could be the fix was sloppy and only fixed the one case that the author of that bug reported, and not similar cases.